# how to add text to loading icon css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have css which displays loading icon on page like below

```
#loading {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: 'icon.gif';
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
```

How can I add text above loading icon e.g. "loading text"
I tried

```
#loading:after{
content: "loading text";
}
```

But it displays text on left top of page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
#loading:after{
  content: "Loading text";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using absolute position on `#loading:after`. Then you can easily position the pseudo-element with respect to `#loading` parent's position

Answer (score 0):

After setting up `position: relative;` parent then try this:

```
#loading:after {
    content: "loading text";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: edited, you mean add `position: relative` to `#mask.loading{...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loadingImage" >
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/82092/screenshots/1073359/spinner.gif"  alt="">
  </div>
</div>


#loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background : #fff;
}

.loadingImage {
    position:relative;
    top : 50%;
    left : 50%;
    margin-left : -50px;
    margin-top : -50px;
}

.loadingImage img {
  width : 100px
}

.loadingImage:after{
content: "loading text";
  position:absolute;
  top:-30px;
  left : 0
}
```