# Add custom text 'Loading..' untill data fetch from API

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

Is there any way show 'Loading' text until data fetch from api. As of now it is showing no data to display

I gone through the documentation did not found anything

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638503/how-to-add-text-to-loading-icon-css

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below:

In .ts file:

```
isLoading = false;

doRequest() {
  isLoading = true;
  this.servis.doRequest()
    .pipe(finalize(() -> this.isLoading = false))
    .subscribe(data => {
     // do smth
     })
}
```

in .html

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading">Your content</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```